# Push notification custom icon and big picture corona sdk

Tags: push-notification, coronasdk, onesignal

I have to send push notification from my own server page.

Currently i can send title,desc,number.but icon,small icon,big picture are cannot send.it is possible or not.using oneSignal i send big-picture but i have to use my own server to push a message.below json value working fine if there i can  add icon and big-picture.

> jsonMessage = '{"data":{"alert":{"title": "My Title","body": "My body of text.","number": 5}},"registration_ids":["'..googleRegistrationId..'"]}'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Corona Enterprise or the Simulator?

If you're using the Corona Simulator you will need the following files in your root project folder to customize the small icon.

- For Android 3.0 and higher. These icons are expected to be white.

  - `IconNotificationDefault-mdpi-v11.png` 24x24 pixels
  - `IconNotificationDefault-hdpi-v11.png` 36x36 pixels
  - `IconNotificationDefault-xhdpi-v11.png` 48x48 pixels
  - `IconNotificationDefault-xxhdpi-v11.png` 72x72 pixels
- For Android 2.3 devices. These icons are expected to be grey.

  - `IconNotificationDefault-mdpi.png` 24x24 pixels
  - `IconNotificationDefault-hdpi.png` 36x36 pixels
  - `IconNotificationDefault-xhdpi.png` 48x48 pixels
  - `IconNotificationDefault-xxhdpi.png` 72x72 pixels

You can use the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) to create the above icon sizes and colors for you. You just need to rename the files to match the above names and move the individual files so they are all in your project's root directory.

You can only change the default small icon and can not set the small icon dynamically due to restrictions with builds from the Corona Simulator.

To set a large icon create an image named ic_onesignal_large_icon_default.png 192x192 in size in your root project folder. If you would like to change it based on the notification your sending give it any name you like then enter its name in the Large Icon field on our site to set it.

If you're using Corona Enterprise see the OneSignal [Android Customizing Notifications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations) page to customize the icons.

Also the format of your json to send a OneSignal notification is not correct. See the [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) POST REST API call for details on the format. There is example code at the bottom of the page to get you started.

Thanks.